# PHP: Using different Windows user credentials with APACHE and WAMP Server

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, wamp

In my company we are currently running a WAMP server with SQLSRV drivers for our BD query's, we are looking to use Windows Authentication for SQLSRV connection instead of SQL AUTH , But **the default Windows User where the WAMP server is different from the user we need to access the SQLSRV host**.

Im looking for a way to change the credentials from the default user to a new user when using Windows Authentication in PHP. I was wondering if is possible to do it from Apache configuration or other tool inside WAMP server.

I have tried starting Apache service as a different user, and the entire WAMP server as different user, but make no difference.